# use sed to execute a shell script if search fails

Tags: linux, centos, sed

I am doing

```
sed "s/test1/replacetext" testfile.txt
```

I am trying use /q for failure to find 'test1' and execute a shell script. How can I do that?
Thank you
Nate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `sed` and multiple lines of input:

```
sed -n '/pattern/{h;s//replacement/;};p;${g;//!q1;}' file
```

- On lines which contain `pattern`:

  - Add the line to the hold buffer
  - Perform substitution
- print every line
- When the last line (`$`) is reached:

  - get the hold buffer
  - If the pattern space doesn't contain `pattern`, quit with exit code `1`
- Empty regular expressions `//` use the last used regex pattern

---

Alternative – `awk`:

```
awk 'END{exit !repl} /pattern/{repl++; sub(/pattern/,"replacement")} 1' file
```

- If a line contains `pattern`, the variable `repl` is incremented & the replacement is made
- At the end, exit with the `logical not` of the variable (if `repl` is zero, exit with status `1`)

---

Alternative – `grep` the input beforehand, e.g.:

```
if grep -q 'pattern' file; then
    # input contains pattern - do sed replacement
    sed 's/pattern/replacement/' file
else
    : input does not contain pattern - execute shell script
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, I want to use sed /q option for single line execution